# Retrieving ArcGIS:s Spatial Data into a Database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, geometry, xml

I have created a vector map with lots of spatial data in geometry flat in with measurement kilometer. The following object that is used in the map will be point, line and polygon object.

I create my own spatial data in ArcGIS without retrieving any data from a database.

How do I retrieve the objects' X and Y coordinate data from ArcGIS into SQL server? Maybe using XML document or does ArcGIS have a local built-in database?

Comment: local built-in database = file geodatabase. There are some improvements at 10.1 http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//016w00000031000000

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that I understand your question but, if I do, try using [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000035000000) to copy features from your file geodatabase to SQL Server:

> Copies features from the input feature class or layer to a new feature
>   class. If the input is a layer which has a selection, only the
>   selected features will be copied. If the input is a geodatabase
>   feature class or shapefile, all features will be copied.